# How to instruct cron to execute a job in airflow Run every 3rd Jan, 3rd April, 3rd July, 3rd Oct at 11:00 AM UTC Time Zone

Tags: cron, airflow, airflow-scheduler

How to instruct cron to execute a job in airflow Run every 22nd Jan, 22nd April, 22nd July, 22nd Oct at 11:00 AM  UTC Time Zone.

I have written below cron command to execute in airflow but it is not running at per scheudled

**`schedule_interval="0 11 22 1/3 *"`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cron-to-human-translator such as [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#0_11_22_1,4,7,10_*) is a convenient tool for writing cron expressions:

```
0 11 22 1,4,7,10 *
```

- `0` = Minute 0
- `11` = Hour 11
- `22` = Day 22
- `1,4,7,10` = Months January, April, July, and October
- `*` = Any day of the week

By default, UTC is applied in Airflow, but you can configure this globally (`AIRFLOW__CORE__DEFAULT_TIMEZONE`), or per DAG. See documentation: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/timezone.html#default-time-zone.